Kiddush Cup Minhag pretaining to the woman of the house
I'm not sure where this minhag originates from but I have frequented a breslover maggids house frequently for shabbos and I noticed that whenever he made kiddush he would always pour from the cup into other cups to distribute and always handed the kiddush cup to the woman of the house. I do not believe he ever drinks from the bekher himself.

Does he drink some of the wine himself from some other cup? Regardless, this may very well have something to do with avoiding problems during Nidah, and then keeping the practice the same all other times.

See brachot 51b ומשגרו לאנשי ביתו במתנה כי היכי דתתברך דביתהו ... א"ל רב נחמן לישדר מר כסא דברכתא לילתא

It can also be necessary for health reasons (high level of sugar in his blood). A cup of grape juice contains 34 g of sugar, which is quite a bit.

@YDJ you only need to drink about 1/8 of a cup, so like 8g sugar

Welcome to MiYodeya Yosef and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

@DoubleAA do you mean 1/4.25 of the cup, 34/4.25 = 8, i.e. slighly more than a 1/4?

He drinks from the other cups. I asked him about it this past shabbos and his answer was because the bekher belongs to the woman of the house. I think this is a really beautiful minhag to have and want to learn more.

@YDJ A cup is 240 ml and you only need to drink about 40. I'm guessing I did 24/4=8 but it's really 6. So 1/6 of a cup is ~6g.

Minhag Breslev is to recite kiddish over a koss containing 3 revyisn of wine and drink one revyis on Friday night leaving the (covered) koss with the remaining two revyisn on the table for Shabess (one revyis for the morning kiddish and one for the havduleh). Some use smaller cups each time. Mind that the mekadesh must drink from the koss, unless he has some health issues or be a nozir, in which case he may delegate his kiddish wine to someone who heard his kiddish, provided they are above 6 years of age.
As for women you might like to check out Magen Avruhom on S"A O"Ch 271. Specifically, in 271:2 he states: "Women are obligated in Kiddush, even though it is a positive commandment that time causes, because זכור is compared to שמור. And these women, since they are included in שמירה, they are included in זכירה. And they can discharge men (from their obligation) since they are obligated מן התורה like them." This probably refers to those women who haven't prayed mayrev, which might be the case.
I'm not sure if the ownership of the koss makes any difference for the established custom. So, probably, your maggid knows that in terms of kabboleh the koss represents Malchess (while wine is Daas) and the woman is also Malchess  (while the man is Zayr Anpin), so it seems like a very weird zivveg? But this is not minhag Breslev.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thank you for your comment. The rules of the site require that the comments directly answer the question asked. As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
